# Is there a way to alter only the printable invoice for Ubercart 3.8?

Tags: ubercart, commerce

Client would like to print order invoices from 'View Orders' page without their large logo at the top wasting ink. I do not seem to be able to isolate just the printed invoice without affecting the admin and customer invoice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible solutions:

- Create separate template called "when_client_prints" and link to this    template from Views Orders.
- Edit current invoice template within your custom module with the logic like `if user hasn't id * then show the logo`. (`*` stands for the `UID` of client account)